# How long does my login last through the AtTask REST API?

Tags: rest, attask

When I use `{domain}/attask/api/login?username={name}&password={pass}` it returns a sessionID. How long can I use that sessionID before I need to log in again? I have checked the documentation and the response does not include a expiration time.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a question that only the service operator can answer.  You should be contacting them and asking them to update their documentation, not posting on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Go to ***Setup > System > Preferences*** and whatever option is selected in the "Automatically log users out after..." drop-down is your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually configurable in your AtTask system.  In the setup area you can set session length.

Answer (score 0):

The session TTL is the same through the API as it is through a regular web login. I believe it's 24 hours.